# Where can I get Cerebral Accelerators?

Tags: eve-online

I am planning on activating a new account and have read about items called Cerebral Accelerators - in fact, there is a page for them on the [EVE Online wiki](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Cerebral_Accelerator) detailing the performance gains they give for new characters during the training process in their initial weeks, but I can't seem to find anywhere that I can get them from.

I'm pretty sure they're still in game on account of them being mentioned as one of the bonuses of the Amarr starter pack on sale on EVE, but I don't see any listed on EVE Central.

Where can I get Cerebral Accelerators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a limited time offer for new accounts only, and the offer has since ended - though I think some of them had been a part of other limited time deals as well.

From [the same page](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Cerebral_Accelerator) as you linked:

> This item was introduced for a limited time starting on 2011.10.28 and was given free to all new pilots through the redeem system.
>
> At a first glance this item seems severely overpowered, but as it is actually impossible to use on players older than 35 days and thus with extremely low SP, this item actually provides quite a large boost to a new players effectiveness without allowing that new player to get anywhere near an older players skill at damage dealing.

Comment: It doesn't look like its ended to me since it's still listed on [Steam's EVE page under Amarr Starter Pack](http://store.steampowered.com/app/8500/)! Does this mean the only way to get them now is through offers like these?

Comment: @kalina Correct, and it is a completely different offer from [the original release](http://community.eveonline.com/news/news-channels/eve-online-news/free-cerebral-accelerator-for-all-new-pilots/). So no, it has ended, but as I said, it is part of other deals. You can find them via contracts, but not on the open market.

Comment: via contracts! Why didn't I think of that?